# .NET Disassembling, edit and patch

Tags: .net, edit, patch, disassembly, ida

I need to edit a .NET executable. I'm new to HEX editing. I have imported it to IDA 6.1 Pro and edited it in IDA-View Window.

Original:

```
ldstr    "Uri : "
```

I changed to (Right click>Manual...(Manual Operand)):

```
ldstr    "Uri : localhost"
```

I have installed PatchDiff2 (IDA Plugin), but this does not work for me:

```
Scanning for functions ...
parsing second idb...
Error: IDB2 parsing cancelled or failed.
```

Is there another way to commit changes to executable?
The original byte value is: `72 BD 1B 00 70 02 7B 59 00 00 04 28 1B 00 00 0A`

How do I get the (I need it to patch from Edit\Patch program\chenge Bytes) new HEX value of

```
ldstr    "Uri : localhost"
```

Comment: IDA would not be my first choice of tool.  Just use ildasm.exe to decompile the assembly, edit the IL, put humpty-dumpty back together with ilasm.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use ildasm instead of IDA. And it work perfect.

> IDA would not be my first choice of tool. Just use ildasm.exe to
>   decompile the assembly, edit the IL, put humpty-dumpty back together
>   with ilasm.exe

Thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)